# Set Regarding in Dynamics 365 App For Outlook

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-365, dynamics365-app-outlook

I have the functionality to send an email when the case is created in Dynamics 365 and the regarding is set as the Case which is created.

But in Dynamics 365 App for Outlook, I don't see the regarding field tracked as in the below image:

[Set Regarding In Dynamics 365 App For Outlook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtevS.png)

Please share your suggestions on this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually **Tracking** is just a clone/copy operation of Outlook object like Email/Appointment to avoid duplicate data entry in Dynamics side. So users will **Track** or **Set Regarding** in Outlook to ship that Email/Meeting into Dynamics as an Activity record. In the background, SSS will map the ExchangeId, CRMId for further handshakes. Moreover this is to see all activities in one place like Timeline or Activities view or regarding record.

What you are doing is sending out Email from Dynamics, this is going to be in Dynamics activities view/Timeline under regarding record. But you are not going to get the reverse behavior in Outlook as its not originated there.

Even if you track it again in outlook - it won't recreate in Dynamics. I tested all these in my environment, the same behavior exists.

Further replies/forwards will be auto-tracked like Ankuser said.

Read more: [Aaron's Blog series](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crminthefield/archive/2018/12/03/dynamics-365-app-for-outlook-part-1-the-basics)

Answer (score 0):

You will get Tracked when you receive a reply to this email. 
For use case Send email from some other user and ask this user to reply back to you in outlook. Once they reply back you will have tracked to particular case.

[image]